# SQL server- process blocked by -2

Tags: sql-server-2005, biztalk

I have a Windows server 2003 which has Biztalk Server 2006 enterprise Edition and SQL server 2005 on it.

I have had messages like process blocked by -2 in SQL server logs on the same server.
I tried killing that process but blocking comes back after some time.

I have applied the following hotfixes after someone suggested:

FIX: Orphaned cache instances may be built in the Instances and Hosts Queue tables of the BizTalkMsgBoxDb database in BizTalk Server 2006 and in BizTalk Server 2006 R2 KB944426

FIX: Routing failure reports are not removed from the Q_Suspended table on a BizTalk Server 2006 server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941690/en-us
 on it.

This seemed to solve the problem for some time. But I have been seeing these "blocked by -2" message in SQL server logs lately.

Any ideas what I should do now?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes with a spid of -2 are failed distributed transactions which are trying to clean them selves up.

This [page](http://www.sqlserverclub.com/articles/how-to-deal-with-negative-spids-in-sql-server.aspx) provides some more info.

Comment: Thanks. 
I will killed the -2 process. Lets see if it happens again.
What if it happens again? Should I just kill it again?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  That or let it complete what its doing.  It is doesn't seam like it's going to finish then killing it would be the correct option.